# How to lock record for editing while using .net

Tags: sql, .net, locking

Hi Guys I'd like to lock a record to prevent editing when Admin and User want to editing the same record in DB in the same time

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = Connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = @"
                    UPDATE   [dbo].[Property]
                    SET     {not important}IS NULL THEN NULL
                                               ELSE geography::Point(@Location_Lat, @Location_Long, 4326) 
                                            END)
                            {not important}
                    WHERE    [Id] = @Id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddParams(property);
                cmd.Connection.Open();

                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use dbms Amazon aurora

Comment: Maybe `sp_getapplock`? Do not be tempted to hold a transaction open for any length of time, it's a really bad idea.